# SonarQube - Make "account" transient or serializable

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I have the following class structure,

```
public interface EnterpriseData extends Serializable {
}

public interface ExtraData extends Serializable {
}

@Getter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserAccount implements EnterpriseData {

    @JsonProperty("account")
    private AccountData account;

    //No handwritten methods in this class
}


@Getter
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AccountData implements ExtraData {

    //Some String fields and setter methods for those fields.

}
```

When I run the SonarQube for the above classes, I get the `Make "account" transient or serializable` error in SonarQube as a Critical issue.

UserAccount and AccountData are two simple classes, and there are another couple of classes that implement the `EnterpriseData` and `ExtraData` interfaces similar to the above ones. Also, those classes have similar implementation similar to the above classes.
And I'm not getting that Sonar issue for those classes.

And when I implement the `Serializable` directly in the `AccountData` class definition, the Sonar is no longer showing that error.

I'm using IntelliJ by adding the SonarLint plugin, and it is configured with the SonarQube server but the SonarLint is not showing that error from the beginning.
I would like to get some insight/fixes about this weird issue.

I'm using Jackson and Lombok in these classes. SonarQube version is 9.8.0.

Comment: I cannot see a real problem in the code. Maybe the implementation of the rule has a bug? What happens when you remove the annotations?

Comment: I tried removing annotations but nothing changed, also as I mentioned, there are another couple of classes which has the same annotations and inheritance and there is no error in there. I'm also thinking about whether this is a sonar rule implementation bug or not.

Comment: Started a discussion in the Sonar community, let's see.
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/make-a-property-serializable-when-serializable-implemented-through-inheritance/84699